# Should I be using a constructor / prototype?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

```
function setupMapObjects() {
    lootChest = new PIXI.Sprite(frame("images/chest.png", 0, 0, 50, 50));
    lootChest.x = 200;
    lootChest.y = 200;
    lootChest.anchor.x = 0.5;
    lootChest.anchor.y = 0.7;
    lootChest.closed = true;
    lootChest.opening;
    lootChest.frameCycle = 0;
    lootChest.interactive = true;
    lootChest.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(lootChest.x, lootChest.y, 10);
    lootChest.on('click', openChest);
    Map.addChild(lootChest);    



    lootChest2 = new PIXI.Sprite(frame("images/chest.png", 0, 0, 50, 50));
    lootChest2.x = 400;
    lootChest2.y = 400;
    lootChest2.anchor.x = 0.5;
    lootChest2.anchor.y = 0.7;
    lootChest2.closed = true;
    lootChest2.opening;
    lootChest2.frameCycle = 0;
    lootChest2.interactive = true;
    lootChest2.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(lootChest2.x, lootChest2.y, 10);
    lootChest2.on('click', openChest);
    Map.addChild(lootChest2);
};


function openingChest() {
    this.texture.frame = new PIXI.Rectangle(this.frameCycle*50, 0, 50, 50);
    if (this.frameCycle === 3) {
        clearInterval(this.opening); 
    } else {
        this.frameCycle++;    
    };
};


function openChest() {
    if (distance(Player.sprite.x, Player.sprite.y, this.x, this.y) < 50) {
        if (this.closed) {
            this.opening = setInterval(openingChest.bind(this), 100);
            this.frameCycle = 1;
            this.closed = false; 
        };
    };
};
```

I have 2 treasure chest sprites that open when clicked and the player is near. Now I am trying to figure out an efficient way to creating 50 of them. How bad would it be to keep making them as I already have and what are some alternatives?

Comment: Yup, this is a school example of where OOP should be used, go for it. Imagine you went on like this, and decided to add, say, a `z` property to each chest.

Comment: Should I use all the properties in the constructor and then change them whenever I create a new one? It seemed kind of pointless, when I was trying it, to just rename all the properties if I have to change most of them later.

Comment: You should pass in as parameters those properties that can change (such as the coordinates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor seems like the right idea. After all, you don't want to have to name each and every chest (`lootChest1`..`lootChest50`). Not to mention, you make sure all of your chests are created equally. So something like this ought to work well.

```
function Chest(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.anchor.x = 0.5;
  this.anchor.y = 0.7;
  this.closed = true;
  this.opening;
  this.frameCycle = 0;
  this.interactive = true;
  this.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(lootChest.x, lootChest.y, 10);
  this.on('click', openChest);
}

// Have them "inherit" from PIXI.Sprite
Chest.prototype = new PIXI.Sprite(frame("images/chest.png", 0, 0, 50, 50));

// How to use it
var lootChest = new Chest(200, 200);
```

It's been a little while since I worked with PIXI so I don't recall if this style of inheritance works with their rendering system. If it doesn't, you can make it a factory function. The factory function would look just like how you're creating your first chest (except you'll want to assign it to a local variable) then return that chest from the function.

**Edit:** The factory method would look something like this:

```
function createChest(x, y) {
  var chest = new PIXI.Sprite(frame("images/chest.png", 0, 0, 50, 50));
  chest.x = x;
  chest.y = y;
  chest.anchor.x = 0.5;
  chest.anchor.y = 0.7;
  chest.closed = true;
  chest.opening;
  chest.frameCycle = 0;
  chest.interactive = true;
  chest.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(lootChest.x, lootChest.y, 10);
  chest.on('click', openChest);
  return chest;
}

// How to use it
var lootChest = createChest(200, 200);
```

I have an [example of how to inherit from PIXI.Sprite](https://github.com/MCluck90/psykick2d/blob/master/src/components/gfx/sprite.js) but it's a little complicated. The way it was done there was to allow configurability since it's in a game engine but if you know exactly what you want your objects to look like, either of the aforementioned methods should be just fine.

Comment: Fixed this.x and this.y

Comment: That looks a lot better than what I was doing. If I create 50 like that, how would I be able to ID them individually for the contents inside?

Comment: @Gyldstrand There's a few ways. My suggestion would be to give them some kind of property (`this.contents = []`) that has their contents. You could also pass that through the constructor.

Comment: This method causes error because of the sprite not being defined for the properties to use.

Comment: @Gyldstrand Okay, then you'll have to go the factory pattern route. I've given notes about how to go about it but I'll throw some code together as well.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about MIKE C! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use OOP (Object Oriented Programming) for this. You could make a array of `Chest` objects and then just modify the constructor function and prototype methods instead of meticulously going through every single chest.

Shomz has got it right.

Then, if you want to, say, animate all of the chests, just use a `for` loop to iterate through the array of `Chest`s and easily do something with all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Mike C gave a good example, but I'd like to expand a bit further with some pitfalls related to prototypes in JavaScript.

Mozilla has a very good example on prototype inheritance and constructors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

But there are some important pitfalls to remember when taking advantage of prototypes, which I have demonstrated in [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxpjKd).

Note that the **same** method being invoked on the **same** object actually behaved differently the second time it was invoked than the first. This is because the object does not store a reference to a given implementation of the `move` function, but instead uses the one that currently resides on its prototype at the time that it is invoked.

It is possible for `Shape.prototype.move` to be modified while your code is running. It is probable that this would never happen, but if it does (like if another developer on your team redefines a function on the prototype at runtime without knowing that one of the same name already exists), it can end up causing a bug which will be very difficult to track down.

Prototypes in JavaScript can be useful tools, but I personally prefer to use the factory pattern to avoid the possibility of elusive prototype-related bugs.

Example:

```
function CreateShape(newX, newY) {
  return {
    x = newX,
    y = newY,
    move = function(addX, addY){
      this.x += addX;
      this.y += addY;
      console.info('Shape moved.');
    }
  }
}
```

By using this pattern, you create a new object each time which does not share a prototype with any of your other objects, meaning that it will always behave the same, no matter what modifications are made to your other Shape objects or any prototype.

Just an alternative for you to consider. I hope this helps!

Comment: If x and y refer to the sprite's x and y, where would you define the sprite at?

function Chest(x, y) {
    this.sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(frame("images/chest.png", 0, 0, 50, 50));
    this.sprite.x = x;
    this.sprite.y = y;
};

doesn't seem to work based on the earlier answer.

Comment: Hmm, did you remember to use the new keyword? var lootChest = Chest(200, 200); will not behave the same as var lootChest = new Chest(200, 200);

Comment: Yeah I did. The edited version works now. Thanks for the assistance. Keep the the world spinning.